# Generate OpenAPI RestTemplate Client with Client Credentials Oauth2 Auth: How to obtain Access Token?

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I'm currently setting up a RestTemplate client using the Maven plugin for OpenAPI3. I've provided an OAuth Client Credentials security scheme and I've set it up as my global security:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
  OAuth2:
    type: oauth2
    flows:
      clientCredentials:
        authorizationUrl: https://someurl.somewhere/auth
        tokenUrl: https://someurl.somewhere/token
        scopes:
          read: Grants read access
          write: Grants write access

security:
  - OAuth2:
    - read
    - write
```

What bugs me is the fact, that there is absolutely no code being generated, which tries to receive the access token from the provided auth endpoint. The only OAuth related method I can find is:

```
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken)
```

But this means that I have to write the code to retrieve the token. Should I do that?

Furthermore my expectation was, that I'll just provide OAuth endpoints, client ID and client secret in the final application, which would use the client.

Comment: Did you end up rolling your own solution?

Comment: Kind of, yes. We switched from RestTemplate to WebClient, since RestTemplate will be deprecated. We bascially did something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webclient-oauth2. You can archieve the same with RestTemplate and some kind of filter I believe.